# How to stash my previous commit?

Tags: git

I've got the following situation on my `git log`:

```
commit 111  <-- need to push it to the repository

commit 222  <-- need to stash this one

...
```

As you can see, I need to push only last (without previous) commit to repository.

How can I do it? `git revert --soft commit_hash` will help me?

Comment: Is there any reason you're wanting to stash the previous commit? Do you plan to use any of the changes made in *commit 222*?

Comment: Yes, I want to use changes in commit 222 in the nearest future. But to push commit 111 and not to merge it with commit 222, I need somehow to stash  commit 222.

Comment: unfortunately there is still no answer that takes the commit message of the commit into account (it could easily be transformed to the stash message), and I am seeing no `git stash` features that enable that easily, which confuses me.

Answer (score 118, accepted):

If you've not pushed either commit to your remote repository, you could use interactive rebasing to 'reorder' your commits and stash the (new) most recent commit's changes only.

Assuming you have the tip of your current branch (commit 111 in your example) checked out, execute the following:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

This will open your default editor, listing most recent 2 commits and provide you with some instructions. Be very cautious as to what you do here, as you are going to effectively 'rewrite' the history of your repository, and can potentially lose work if you aren't careful (make a backup of the whole repository first if necessary). I've estimated commit hashes/titles below for example

```
pick 222 commit to be stashed
pick 111 commit to be pushed to remote

# Rebase 111..222 onto 333
#
# Commands:
#  p, pick = use commit
#  r, reword = use commit, but edit the commit message
#  e, edit = use commit, but stop for amending
#  s, squash = use commit, but meld into previous commit
#  f, fixup = like "squash", but discard this commit's log message
#  x, exec = run command (the rest of the line) using shell
#
# These lines can be re-ordered; they are executed from top to bottom.
#
# If you remove a line here THAT COMMIT WILL BE LOST.
#
# However, if you remove everything, the rebase will be aborted.
#
# Note that empty commits are commented out
```

Reorder the two commits (they are listed oldest => newest) like this:

```
pick 111 commit to be pushed to remote
pick 222 commit to be stashed
```

Save and exit, at which point git will do some processing to rewrite the two commits you have changed. Assuming no issues, you should have reversed the order of your two changesets. This can be confirmed with `git log --oneline -5` which will output newest-first.

At this point, you can simply do a soft-reset on the most recent commit, and stash your working changes:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git stash
```

It's important to mention that this option is only really viable if you have not previously pushed any of these changes to your remote, otherwise it can cause issues for everyone using the repository.

Comment: If the commits have been pushed, but the commit to be stashed is already the last one, is it as bad?

Comment: If that commit has been pushed to the remote then it will require you to do a force-push as you are rewriting public history. This may not be a problem in your case, but it will depend on your team size and how many people are likely to have the branch you are changing in their local repositories.

Comment: Even after having pushed, if the scope of your changes is within the context of a trunk-based development -highly recommended good practice-, an interactive rebase is going to be safe in most cases (the potential of re-writing history is limited to your branch).
You would only need to force push afterwards, using `git push --force-with-lease` if working with other people on the same branch so you do not overwrite anyone's changes inadvertently

Answer (score 16):

If it were me, I would avoid any risky revision editing and do the following instead:

1. Create a new branch on the SHA where 222 was committed, basically as a bookmark.
2. Switch back to the main branch. In it, revert commit 222.
3. Push all the commits that have been made, which will push commit 111 only, because 222 was reverted.
4. Work on the branch from step #1 if needed. Merge from the trunk to it as needed to keep it up to date. I wouldn't bother with stash.

When it's time for the changes in commit 222 to go in, that branch can be merged to trunk.

Comment: There is an even easier way if it is only for a short time: Save the hash of the commit, revert the commit, do your work and then cherry-pick it again. Due to gits leniency a deleted dangling commit will still stay around for quite a while (something like 30 or even 90 days).

Answer (score 10):

An alternative solution uses the stash:

**Before:**

```
~/dev/gitpro $git stash list

~/dev/gitpro $git log --oneline -3

* 7049dd5 (HEAD -> master) c111
* 3f1fa3d c222
* 0a0f6c4 c333
```

1. **git reset head~1** <--- head shifted one back to c222; working still contains c111 changes
2. **git stash push -m "commit 111"** <--- staging/working (containing c111 changes) stashed; staging/working rolled back to revised head (containing c222 changes)
3. **git reset head~1** <--- head shifted one back to c333; working still contains c222 changes
4. **git stash push -m "commit 222"** <--- staging/working (containing c222 changes) stashed; staging/working rolled back to revised head (containing c333 changes)
5. **git stash pop stash@{1}** <--- oldest stash entry with c111 changes removed & applied to staging/working
6. **git commit -am "commit 111"** <-- new commit with c111's changes becomes new head

**note** you cannot run 'git stash pop' without specifying the stash@{1} entry. The stash is a LIFO stack -- not FIFO -- so that would incorrectly pop the stash@{0} entry with c222's changes (instead of stash@{1} with c111's changes).

**note** if there are conflicting chunks between commits 111 and 222, then you'll be forced to resolve them when attempting to pop.  (This would be the case if you went with an alternative rebase solution as well.)

**After:**

```
~/dev/gitpro $git stash list

stash@{0}: On master: c222

~/dev/gitpro $git log -2 --oneline

* edbd9e8 (HEAD -> master) c111
* 0a0f6c4 c333
```

Answer (score 4):

As usual in Git, there are many ways to skin this cat, but because we're talking about 2 commits (rather than many), the simplest thing that comes to mind upon reading this question is:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2 # set branch to point to 2 commits ago (parent of 222)
git cherry-pick 111
git push
git cherry-pick 222
```

The question asks about stashing the previous commit, but I would think under normal circumstances you wouldn't need to anymore since you've already accomplished your goal of pushing the desired commit. So you would be done here and can go on with your development. But if you still want to stash your top commit instead, you would continue with:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git stash
```

Note: the reason this is (slightly) easier than an interactive rebase is because there are only 2 commits to cherry pick, and you likely want to push in between them.

Answer (score 1):

It's works for me;

1. Checkout on commit that is a origin of current branch.
2. Create new branch from this commit.
3. Checkout to new branch.
4. Merge branch with code for stash in new branch.
5. Make soft reset in new branch.
6. Stash your target code.
7. Remove new branch.

I recommend use something like a SourceTree for this.

Answer (score 1):

I solving doing this:

Remove the target commit

> git revert --strategy resolve 222

Save commit 222 to patch file

> git diff HEAD~2 HEAD~1 > 222.patch

Apply this patch to unstage

> patch -p1 < 222.patch

Push to stash

> git stash

Remove temp file

> rm -f 222.patch

Very simple strategy in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I found most of these answers confusing, so what I would do is:

```
git reset <hash of commit right before 222> --mixed
```

This will undo the change from both 111 and 222 and they won't be staged either. You can then stage the changes you want and when you're ready, stash the rest of the changes, and commit. Then you can stash pop your changes and commit them if desired.