# How can I undo my last commit in Git and stash those changes instead?

Tags: git

I have a branch called `feat-a` and I essentially want to "undo" my last local commit and just have those files staged. Then when they are all staged I want to stash those changes.

Now what I'm doing does sound a bit backwards, but the cause of this issue was a force push on master to re-write some commit authors, so doing a merge or rebase of master onto/into `feat-a` just completely breaks with a ton of conflicts even though master and feat-a are only off by one commit.

I have read through a similar question here: [How to stash my previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26884364/how-to-stash-my-previous-commit)

But it isn't necessarily what I want to do. I just want to unstage and stash my last direct commit, versus what that user wanted (i.e. pull a commit out from between other commits).

Comment: You are using the word "staged" incorrectly.  You do not need or want to stage the changes before you stash them. You want the changes to appear in the working directory, but not in the index.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the heads up. Let me know if you have any good resources on that vocabulary, but I've almost always been using `staging` area for anything that is added there via `git add .`

Comment: Thanks for that @eftshift0

Comment: I have deleted the previous comment and corrected it (I mis-wrote wrote a word and it makes it redundant....). I meant: @WilliamPursell Reading your comments now (even though an answer was accepted). I think he is using the terms correctly. The only thing I would say is that for files that are already tracked, there's no need to stage the changes in order to stash them... however for new files, if you want to stash them, you have to **add** them (or use up a little more of your brain memory to learn and use one of the options from git-stash, if there's any to include new files when stashing).

Answer (score 76, accepted):

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
git stash save "Saving instead" # or something like that
```

Comment: Just an FYI: In case **if it's pushed and you want to revert & stash it**, we can use `git cherry-pick <commit_id>` it before entering the commands mentioned above.

Comment: As a remark to your remark, the cherry-pick stays an option even *after* resetting/stashing. The commit isn't destroyed instantly, it will stay available for inspection or cherry-pick until it's ultimetely garbage collected.