# Tack back a commit i GIT?

Tags: git, azure, commit

I'm using Git with Azure and Visual Studio 2022. I made some changes and staged everything for a stash, but it got committed instead. I can see the commit in outgoing(not pushed to remote yet), but I don't see how to easily take the commit back. I have tried Revert that just adds another commit just to cancel the prev. I also tried Reste > Keep changes. but that just removed all other commits in the outgoing queue.

So, I now got I commit in outgoing, and I want it back in to my code, how do I do this? Best would be if it could be done with the GUI and not special GIT commands.

Its important that the changes is not lost, and I want them back in to my solution(changes).

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52761305/how-can-i-undo-my-last-commit-in-git-and-stash-those-changes-instead/52761334#52761334 withi instructions to take back last commit and then stash it instead. Disclaimer: I provide the answer.

Comment: @eftshift0, but is not git reset --soft HEAD~1 command the same as Reset > Keep Changes from the GUI?